# how to autohide the ui-bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ to display tooltip in the html page developed using AngularJS. I am able to access the tooltip-is-open attribute to show and hide the tooltip. But I am not able to achieve the same thing using a custom directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button tooltip-placement="auto" uib-tooltip="Hide/show tooltip using directive" tooltip-trigger="'click'" tooltip-is-open="true" tooltip-auto-hide>Button 1</button>
  <button tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="Hide/show tooltip using controller" tooltip-trigger="'click'" tooltip-is-open="showHidett" tooltip-auto-hide>Button 2</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.showHidett = true;
    $timeout(function () {
         $scope.showHidett = false;
    }, 2000);

});
app.directive('tooltipAutoHide',function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            tooltipIsOpen :'='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                scope.tooltipIsOpen = true;
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
                }, 2000);
            });
            element.on('mouseleave', function () {
                scope.tooltipIsOpen = false;
            });
        }
    };
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code the tooltip trigger for Button2 which is managed by controller is working but the tooltip trigger for Button1 which is managed by directive is not working. The working example is posted in the following plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/0bwCpPVYDAUiQkW6oIu3?p=preview

Comment: Can you give working fiddle?

Comment: You can find the plunker link here https://plnkr.co/edit/0bwCpPVYDAUiQkW6oIu3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As per guidelines of https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

you can use `tooltip-popup-close-delay` directive to apply hide delay,
and `tooltip-trigger` accept multiple values seperated by space like `mouseenter click` no need of bind external mouse enter events

Refer definitions for these properties,
[image: definition of popupCloseDelay]

Comment: tooltip-popup-close-delay is used to just delay the hiding of tooltip and not to hide the tooltip. And I am manually overriding the triggers only to show the tooltip on hide after specific time interval.

Comment: do you want to open tooltip on click or hover?

Comment: while use isolated scope you may have not set values directly assign like this `tooltip-is-open="tooltipIsOpen"`  https://plnkr.co/edit/9zWieWIRqlkRuuJoEmTa?p=preview